# Relationship between magnetic and electrical permeability constant.

Tags: electromagnetism

In the process of working through physics problems in electromagnetism over the years, I have noticed an interesting relationship that arises from the magnetic permeability constant and the electrical permittivity constant.  If the square root is taken of the magnetic permeability constant divided by the electrical permittivity constant ($\epsilon_0$),the result is 377 $Ω$. (The units work out to ohms after some manipulations). I find it extremely intriguing that free space, i.e. outer space, has an electrical resistivity.  There are interesting implications provided you are willing to consider possibilities that are outside or on the edge of the Standard Model.
I’d appreciate hearing thoughts and reactions to the above relationship between the magnetic permeability and the electrical resistivity.

Comment: Hi, I changed the title of your question, as it should reflect the content of the question. Best of luck with it.

Comment: Also note that $\varepsilon_0 \mu_0 = c^{-2}$. I am not sure why you have to go outside of the standard model. Already in the standard model you have vacuum polarization due to quantum effects.

Comment: So, what is your actual question? The 377 Ω is the well-known "wave impedance" or "wave resistance"  of electromagnetic waves, which gives the ratio of magnitudes of electric to magnetic field strength  of these waves in vacuum.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing mysterious about the 377 Ω obtained by taking the square root of the ratio of permeability and permittivity of free space. This well-known quantity is called "wave impedance" of free space and gives the magnitude ratio of electric and magnetic fields of an electromagnetic wave in vacuum. There is no mysterious relation to anything "on the edge of" and much less beyond the Standard Model. It is just good old Maxwell's theory of electromagnetism.